# invalid token: [node:title] when Token module installed

Tags: 7, tokens

I'm on Drupal 7.80 and a Drupal newb so help with how to debug as well as things to try appreciated.

Taking over a Drupal install that might have some outstanding issues.

**Problem: It looks like 'core' tokens are not available. E.g. `[node:title]`, `[current-page:pager]`, and `[site:name]` are all unavailable**

Detail: When trying to save/preview a custom content type called 'Event' I get a lot of token errors. It looks like they're coming from the Meta tags module which is set by default to populate its fields using tokens. For example Page title in Meta tags is set to: `[node:title] | [current-page:pager][site:name]`, and when saving an Event I get error messages that *none* of those tokens can be found. (I'm assuming Metatag is a use/required core module and I shouldn't attempt to disable it or just remove all these settings)

I have two token modules installed: 'Entity tokens' and 'Token' that both look like core Required modules. I don't know how to check if they're actually installed and working?

The Token Browser only shows 3 top level sections: 'Current Date', 'Current page' and 'Random'.

Is it possible an errant module is removing tokens? How should I debug this?

Thanks for any/all help

**UPDATE**

I found the Flush Cache > Metatag, did this and that has just removed the Metatag panel from all my Content Types, but it does not seem to have re-added 'core' tokens - Token Browser still shows the limited set of tokens as above.

I've also done a 'Flush all caches' now

Answer (score 0):

Despite having flushed caches whilst logged in I clicked 'Flush all caches' whilst logged in as admin user and this seemed to do the trick where click this while logged in as non-admin did not before.

I'm about 90% sure it was this, I was also clicking around with things in the Configuration > Meta Data > Defaults page to see if re-saving settings there did anything but don't think it was this.